# Extract value out of array within an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this

```
records =
[
 ["a","1"],
 ["b","2"],
 ["c","3"]
]
```

I want to pull the number 3, given that I known I am searching for the value of "c".

I've tried this but no luck

```
search_for = 'c'

test = records.select{ |x| x=search_for}
```

I get back the whole array

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for Array#assoc:

```
records.assoc(search_for).last
```

Comment: Nice, but you forgot `.last`. I suggest your write `records.assoc('c').last
 => "3"`. I'll delete this comment when you've seen it (no reply req'd). Also, the link for the method is  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc .

Comment: thanks, I prefer this to changing it to a hash and @CarySwoveland thanks for the fix!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thank you for the fix too. It would be great if you could you leave your comment up with the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert you array to hash and just get the value like this:

```
search_for = 'c'
test = Hash[records][search_for]   #=> "3"
```

You may also consider to use `.key?` to check if key is present.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm pretty new to ruby, what is `.key`?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer: it checks if key is present in the hash.

Comment: `Hash.key?(k)` is the same as `Hash.has_key?(k)` and `Hash.include?(k)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the cleanest or most idiomatic, but here's another way:

```
records.find { |x, y| break(y) if x == "c" }
```

In other words, given an array of pairs `x, y`, `find` the first pair where `x == "c"` and return the value of `y`.

Comment: awesome I really like this answer because it's intuitive enough to understand what to do with the array has more than 2 values, and if the value i'm trying to extract is not `.last` like in seph's* answer

Answer (score 1):

```
test = records.select{ |x| x[0] == search_for }
value = test[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
records.find { |f,_| f == 'c' }.last #=> 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array#include?(value):

Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.include?(3)   # => true
a.include?(9)   # => false
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't what my question was asking. a) this doesn't return the value, b) I don't know the value to begin with, only the associated key, hence "given i know I'm searching for 'c'", so I can't check to see if it's included if I don't know it.